# "Forward" attribute for an option

Tags: options, data, forward

I am downloading implied volatilities for some options. I noticed, however, that I am also able to choose "Forward" as an attribute for the option. What is this? Is it an option written on a forward? I wasn't able to find anything in the Help-menu of my provider, but I suspect it is something very general such as IV, Vega, ...

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't know this platform but my best guess is that this is showing the forward price of the underlying asset. In the simplest case of a non-dividend paying stock: $F=Se^{r(T-t)}$.

Comment: Agree with @oronimbus, but it may be an options implied forward (forwards are an important quantity when needed to [compute a vol surface](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/73891/54838)). In general, you may want to add a few details (underlying, provider, screenshot of the view that displays the forward...)