Best approach to solving for an option’s mid price IV?
As the title implies, I’m having trouble figuring out which approach is best suited to solving for mid price IV, given only a bid price and ask price for an option (assume we also have all necessary parameters to solve for IV such as S, K, T, r, etc).
Approach A - avg the bid price and ask price, the solve for iv on this mid price (Im using Barone-Adesi Whaley to solve for IV).
Ex: Bid price = 1.80 Ask price = 1.90. Therefore Mid price =  (1.80+1.90)/2 = 1.85. Then plug 1.85 into pricing model and solve for IV at the mid to get hypothetical Mid IV = .35
Approach B - solve for iv at the bid price and also solve for iv at the ask price, then avg those 2 results to get mid IV.
Ex: Bid price = 1.80 Ask price = 1.90. Plug 1.80 into a pricing model to get hypothetical IV of .3 and then do the same for 1.90 to get hypothetical IV of .4. Therefore Mid IV = (.3+.4)/2 = .35
As you can see, both approaches reach the same solution of .35 IV at the mid, however my issue lies in deep otm / itm options, where solving for IV on the bid price can lead to a convergence at 0 for the bid IV. This can cause the mid IV to be wildly different between approaches A and B. My goal is to eventually take these mid IVs and interpolate them using something like SVI, but im stuck on which approach is better, and im struggling to find literature that speaks about this issue specifically. Any advice is appreciated, and if you have alternative approaches that you think are superior, id be interested to learn more.

Don't use American options directly in building your vol surface, especially not when using approximations. I suggest to look up de-americanization methods, e.g. https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/73891/54838

This screenshot looks like one from  voladynamics? Why did you include that? If your end goal is matching these, that's going to be a tough one. There is a lot of modelling (dividends, fitting, they use Leisen & Reimer to compute American options, it's not SVI, that particular screenshot is their C6,...)

@AKdemy Correct, if I understand correctly. they are calculating IV for bid ask as well as mid, as you can see each node has 3 dots. Im trying to figure out how they are calculating the mids though (which I assume are the nodes they use to interpolate using their C family of curves). What is throwing me, is that it seems that a few nodes have massive bid ask spreads for IV.

@AKdemy I have my own interpolation model that i created, based on Bergomi and RFV, using a custom objective function similar to weighted least squares. It might not be as good as voladynamics proprietary models, but it gets the job done for the most part, and seems much better than traditional methods like SVI. Thats not my issue. My issue is plotting the data correctly before running an interpolation on it. as I assume they only interpolate the mid IVs.

Issue is I dont quite know how they are solving for mid IVs. as I dont know if they are using approach A, approach B, or another approach I didnt propose in this post.
